# multi-filter search in django not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

There are 3 filters namely description, categories and locations. For description, I want to search a job by a company name, job title or job description.
Even if the user inputs, "company name and job title", i should retrieve a correct match not exactly but somewhat close. How do I get this?

models.py

```
 class Internship(models.Model):

     recruiter = models.ForeignKey(Recruiter, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
     internship_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     internship_mode = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MODE_CHOICES)
     industry_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     internship_desc = RichTextField()

 class Recruiter(models.Model):

     user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
def user_search_internship(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        internship_desc = request.POST['internship_desc']
        internship_ind = request.POST['internship_industry']
        internship_loc = request.POST['internship_location']

      
    results = []
    
    
    if internship_desc != "" and internship_desc is not None:
        query_results = Internship.objects.filter(
            Q(internship_title__icontains=internship_desc) |
            Q(internship_desc__icontains=internship_desc) |
            Q(recruiter__company_name__icontains=internship_desc)
        )
    
    if internship_ind !="" and internship_ind is not None:
        query_results = Internship.objects.filter(
            industry_type__iexact=internship_ind)

    if internship_loc !="" and internship_loc is not None:
        query_results = Internship.objects.filter(
            recruiter__company_region__iexact=internship_loc)

    if query_results:
        for internship in query_results:
            print(internship)
    context = {
            'query_results': query_results,
    }

    return render(request, 'internship_search_results.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Q` object to do `or` operation on filters:

```
    internships = internships.filter(
        Q(internship_title__icontains=internship_desc) |
        Q(internship_desc__icontains=internship_desc) |
        Q(recruiter__company_name__icontains=internship_desc)
    )
```

Comment: what if it is a company having a specific location and category?

Comment: Well, you must know something about the user input string so you can parse it (like a predefined pattern). If you are just getting a raw string and don't know how the string is structured, you can just do your best and return the relevant records by searching through multiple fields.

Comment: thank youuuu for the answer ! :) It works. Having some issues for the location and industry type tho

Comment: You're welcome:)
This works for all fields, you might have a bug in your filtering definitions, check those again and be careful for `_` and `__`.

Comment: can you check if im doing it the right way?

Comment: OK, I get it now. See, when you do a filter it removes all the records that are not a match to the filter, now win your code you filter based on description and it leaves you some records. after that you do another filter on the same records but this time you specify one filter which will wipe out all previous records. You are doing an `and` filter and this most likely gives you a blank query set. you must have three query sets and combine them to get your desired result. To do so use `|` between your query sets: 
final_qs = first_qs | second_qs | third_qs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233351/discussion-between-alpha-and-sina-farahani).